# Cannot send email with Java in Test Server

Tags: java, email, tomcat, tomcat8

I'm using Java Email Sender to send emails in Java.. And I'm using VelocityEngine to send HTML emails.

In my local computer everything is good! The emails are sent.

But when I deploy the code to the test server (which don't have a domain related, just the IP) The connection with gmail fails.

I have my email setting in spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="mail.domain.com" />
        <property name="port" value="25" />
        <property name="username" value="mymail@domain.com" />
        <property name="password" value="*xxxxxx" />

        <property name="javaMailProperties">
           <props>
                  <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                  <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
                  <prop key="mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity">true</prop>
                  <prop key="mail.smtps.ssl.trust">*</prop>
               </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When I try to send the email from the server the error I get said:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.domain.com, port: 25;
```

And then it said, that it is a timeout.. But my question is if is there any security that I need to disabled from the email server or if it's something with tomcat

Comment: Are you actually using `mail.domain.com` as the server host name?

Comment: No... I use the right email and server.... Locally It works, it send the emails that I want, but the issue is in the server...

Comment: Are you sure that the SMTP server is reachable from your test server? Maybe there's a firewall or something similar in the way.

Comment: That sounds like the right reason... but it's weird that from my machine is working...

Comment: That's why a firewall might be involved.

Comment: @Malt I checked and there is no firewall in the server.

Comment: Try connecting to the server using `telnet` or `nc` or something similar. See whether it's possible. It sounds like a networking issue, not something that has to do your code.

Comment: I was a able to make it works using TLS... But I don't know why when the app was running localhost it was working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix this issue using TLS security in the spring-config

So I just have to add

```
<prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity">true</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtps.ssl.trust">*</prop>
```

and changed the port to 587.

Regards